# What LaTeX packages are available for ISO quality system documentation?

Tags: packages, document-classes, iso

I wonder if there are any use cases of TeX/LaTeX for ISO quality system documentation. I understand that the basic classes would suffice for logical document structuring, but I'm just wondering if someone could have written a class or package for such an application.

**UPDATE:**
I am looking into something more like a document management system integrated with LaTeX.

*What aspect of document management am I looking at, for example?*
Quality systems have ***a lot*** of documents that cross-reference each other. For example, **Q01 - Quality Manual** and a five dozen other documents mention **T01 - Test Procedure A** somewhere in the body text and also in its References section. If, sometime in the future, **T01 - Test Procedure A** changes its title to **T01 - Steps In Performing Procedure A**, obviously it will be tedious work to look through the other documents that reference **T01**. Of course, this might require re-compiling the other documents, but that's surely better than wading through them one by one.

Comment: Do you have a example of such a document (like a pdf)?

Comment: The update seems to me to be a whole new question.  Maybe you would like to accept Will's answer and ask afresh?

Comment: I guessed so, too. Thanks for the guidance. The new question is here: [How do I keep cross-references across several documents accurate?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4416/how-do-i-keep-cross-references-across-several-documents-accurate)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may be interested in Peter Wilson's [`iso` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/iso). From the readme:

> The iso class is for typesetting ISO International Standard documents
>   according to the requirements specified in "ISO/IEC Directives, Part 2,
>   Rules for the structure and drafting of International Standards.
>   (Fourth edition, 2001)".

Answer (score 2):

If the cross-reference integrity checking is the only problem, may be the package [xr](http://tug.ctan.org/cgi-bin/ctanPackageInformation.py?id=xr) in CTAN would be of help.