# How do I keep cross-references across several documents accurate?

Tags: cross-referencing, packages, iso

This is a follow-up to [my question about quality system documentation management](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4406/791). That question evolved to a different question and Charles suggested to ask a new one, so I'll just quote it here.

> I am looking into something more like a document management system integrated with LaTeX.
>
> *What aspect of document management am I looking at, for example?*
> Quality systems have a lot of documents that cross-reference each other. For example, **Q01 - Quality Manual** and a five dozen other documents mention **T01 - Test Procedure A** somewhere in the body text and also in its **References** section. If, sometime in the future, **T01 - Test Procedure A** changes its title to **T01 - Steps In Performing Procedure A**, obviously it will be tedious work to look through the other documents that reference **T01**. Of course, this might require re-compiling the other documents, but that's surely better than wading through them one by one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this can be easily achieved with a good reference management system (to me, SVN is great in doing this). All tex files should have in common a bibliograpghic file, and all documents should be listed in that file.

The people in charge of mantaining the T01 document, in case of a change in the bibliographic data, should update the corresponding entry in the `.bib` file (and the changes are tracked by svn).

So, whenever a change in the `.bib` file occurs, the next time the Q01 document is re-compiled, the reference updates automatically.

However, this requires an agreement on how to structure the documents' tree and the use of a versioning system. Subversion helps in both.

Answer (score 1):

The `xr-hyper` and `hyperref` packages are a solution.

Here, an example with two documents.

First, `a.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\section{Test Procedure A}
\label{T01}
Test procedure A...
\end{document}
```

Second, `b.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\externaldocument[a-]{a}

\begin{document}
In document \href{a.pdf}{a.pdf}, you find the section \ref{a-T01} with
title \nameref{a-T01}...
\end{document}
```

If you compile `a.tex` then `b.tex`, you get:

[image]